# Which build systems (apart from make) can interpret the compiler-generated .d dependency files? Is it possible in Bazel?

Tags: makefile, build, bazel

Nowadays most compilers support the generation of .d dependency files that list all includes the c file depends on. This works wonderfully with make.

Is there any other build system that can interpret .d files and fetch the automatically generated dependencies? Or is there a more modern way of automatic dependency handling in the new build systems like Bazel, Gradle, Ninja, Scons etc...? Or am I wrong and auto deps are not that important anymore?

I'm looking into possibly replacing make, but with keeping all its nice functionalities.

Comment: I'm uncertain whether any other build tools provide built-in support for interpreting such files, but I observe that they are trivial for `make` to interpret because they are expressed in `make` syntax.  At least some other build systems provide their own bespoke alternatives, which probably moots the question with respect to those.  Read their docs to find out about how they deal with dependency declaration and tracking.

Comment: That's the problem, did not find it in the docs of any other build system I checked so far. I'm also quite sure that it's impossible for Bazel, because it needs to know all dependencies before the first build, otherwise the files are not provided in the hermetic build environment. So Bazel is out of question.

Comment: I'm sorry if this seems aggressive, but just how hard did you look?  For example, SCons is on your list, and its manual contains [an entire chapter on dependencies](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-depends), with two sections directed towards implicit dependencies.  It took me two minutes to find that.  Perhaps some of the other systems you mentioned are not so well documented, but I'm inclined to think that you're somehow looking in the wrong place or at the wrong docs.

Comment: It's briefly mentioned in chapter 6.5 that .d files do not work properly in SCons (sources will be compiled twice). The rest is not interesting, looking for #include in the C files is no solution, I'm specifically looking for .d file support. I did not go through the docs of all systems so thoroughly, hoped that the experts here can tell by heart or recommend extra tools (not in the core docs) that parse/convert .d files for other build systems. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No, SCons does not use `.d` files.  But the rest of those docs, especially the sections about implicit dependencies that I already mentioned, *should* be interesting, because they explain what Scons does *instead*.  "I'd rather someone else did my research for me" is not an approach that tends to be well received here.  Nor do we generally appreciate being treated as a reference service, if that's how you prefer to view it.

Comment: It is what autoconf, makedepend etc... did 20 years back. It's slow and inaccurate, as conditional compilation, options built-in or provided on the command line are not taken into consideration. This could work with any build system, with some effort.
I want to use the compiler-generated files. They're 100% accurate and generated without extra build steps, extra tools and runtime. I did my research and it's inconclusive - no build systems mention it in the features chapter.

Comment: And *that is the answer* as far as SCons is concerned.

Comment: Then that's a straight no for SCons. Of course, it can handle dependencies, like all build systems, but my question is whether the compiler-generated .d files can be interpreted. Make can do that in at least 2 ways, without unnecessary compilations. (it has plenty of other issues though, I guess you know how miserable it can be)